# What happens when we take the derivative of an implicitly defined function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Consider the function y(x) implicitly decided by this equation: $\sin(xy)=\cos(x+y)$.

The graph on plane looks like this:
[image]

According to my textbook, we can take the derivative of both sides with respect to x to obtain the derivative y'(x)=[some function of x and y].

<s>In this case y'(x) = -(\sin(xy)+y\cos(xy))/(\sin(x+y)+x\cos(xy)).</s>

In this case $y'(x) = -\dfrac{\sin(x+y)+y\cos xy }{\sin(x+y)+x\cos xy }$.

Now evaluate $y'(x)$ at the point $A$. There seems to be two tangent lines at point $A$. Then which slope does $y'(x)$ at $A$ describe?

Comment: When you did the implicit derivtive, what function of $(x,y)$ did you obtain? Or did you obtain two such functions of $(x,y)$ and what were they?

Comment: Well, the textbook skips the existence of a (locally defined) differentiable $y$ such that $\sin(x y(x)) = \cos(x+y(x))$ which is the content of the implicit function theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem (it is not a trivial theorem). If you know such a (differentiable) function exists then you can just differentiate, keeping in mind that $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: @coffeemath yes this is what confuses me. There might be multiple functions implicitly defined at the same time but by following the above mechanical process we can obtain only one value at any point. Sometimes this works fine for example when we do this to a circle x^2+y^2=1 we find all the tangent slope at the same time for both the two half circle functions defined. Then I come up with the example where the lines may intersect as above can cannot understand the problem well.

Comment: The first term in the numerator for $y'$ should be $\sin(x+y)$ instead of $\sin xy$, right?

Comment: Ohhh of course! Yes, you are considering the function defined by the imlicit function theorem, of course. Sorry, my bad! It makes perfect sense! Just deleted my comment, it was useless

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the linkage. So this means it must satisfy some condition to be meaningfully applied.

Comment: @MPW Yes my mistake

Comment: Anyway, the implicit function theorem has some hypotheses, namely some derivative needs to be $\neq 0$ for it to apply. Surely in the point A this hypothesis fails, and thus you cannot apply it

Comment: I would guess that at the point $A$ you get something like $\frac 00$ for the expression for $y'$. It might be instructive to try the same thing  with the equation $y^2 = x^2$, whose graph is a pair of crossed lines with slope $\pm 1$.  If you try to evaluate $y'$ at the crossing point (which is $(0,0)$), you run into trouble.

Comment: @MPW That was exactly the answer I was writing, you should write it. When one has $y'=f(x,y)$, at a point where $f$ is discontinuous one must take $\lim f$ for $(x,y)$ along a path towards that point.

Comment: @elemelons : You go ahead and write it up

Comment: If you can overlay that plot with the plot of $\sin(x+y) +x\cos xy = 0$ (denominator vanishes), you might find the second plot passes through $A$, and ditto with plot of $\sin(x+y) +y\cos xy = 0$ (numerator vanishes).

Comment: @user1206899 Yes indeed. Essentially you need a 'finite slope' of some sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've solved for $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=f(x,y)$, but the function you $f$ you have is not defined everywhere. Indeed, at those points of intersection $(x_0,y_0)$ where there is more than one tangent line, if you try to plug $(x_0,y_0)$ into $f$ you get $0/0$ which is undefined. Instead, you have to take the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)$ along the appropriate portion of $f$'s graph.

A simpler example is $y^2=x^2$ (which is equivalent to $y=\pm x$, which is just a big X). Differentiating and solving yields $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{x}{y}$. Along the path $y=x$ the ratio $\frac{x}{y}$ is identically $1$ so the limit is $1$, whereas on the path $y=-x$ the ratio is identically $-1$ so the limit is $-1$. As you can see by looking at the X, the two possible slopes are indeed $+1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a graph of the implicit function $y$ along with the graphs of the set where the numerator of $y'$ vanishes and the set where the denominator of $y'$ vanishes. Note they all meet at $A$, so your expression for $y'$ becomes $0/0$ at $A$. That means you can't use your expression for $y'$ at the point $A$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It may be of interest to note that the self-intersection points all lie on the lines $ \ y \ = \ n \pi - x \ \ $ or $ \ x + y \ = \ n \pi \ \ . \ $  [The red diagonal line is $ \ x + y \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ the orange lines, $ \ x + y \ = \ \pm \pi \ \ , \ $ the green lines, $ \ x + y \ = \ \pm 2\pi \ \ . \ ] \ $    So at these points, we have $ \ \sin ( \ x·[n \pi - x] \ ) \ = \ \pm 1 \ \ , \ $ with the sign alternating on successive lines (at your point $ \ A \ \ , \ \sin ( \ x·[- \pi - x] \ ) \ = \ -1 \ \ ) \ . \  $

The derivative at these points is then
$$ y' \ \ = \ \ \frac{0 \ + \ (n \pi \ - \ x)·\cos( \ x·[ n \pi \ - \ x ] \ )}{0 \ + \ x·\cos( \ x·[ n \pi \ - \ x ] \ )} \ \ = \ \ \frac{ (n \pi \ - \ x)·\cos( \ x·[ n \pi \ - \ x ] \ )}{x·\cos( \ x·[ n \pi \ - \ x ] \ )} \ \ . $$
Since we have $ \ \sin ( \ x·[- \pi - x] \ ) \ = \ \pm 1 \ $ there, the cosine factors are zero, whence the indeterminate ratio for $ \ y' \ \ (x \ \neq \ 0 \   $ at any of those points).

Why *are* there two curves crossing through point $ \ A \ $ (or any of these other points)?  We can apply the "angle-addition" identities to the two sides of the curve equation to gain (perhaps)  some insight.  On the line $ \ y \ = \ -\pi - x \ \ , \ $ the left side is
$ \ \sin(xy) \ = \ \sin ( \ x·[- \pi - x] \ ) \ \ , \ $ which  becomes

$$ \sin ( \  - \pi·x \ - \ x^2 \ ) \ \ = \ \ -\sin ( \ \pi·x \ + \ x^2 \ ) \ \ = \ \ -[ \ \sin (\pi·x)·\cos(x^2) \ + \ \cos (\pi·x)·\sin(x^2) \ ] \ \ , $$

equal to $   \ \cos (- \pi) \ = \ -1 \   \ $ on the right side.  Introducing a small change in the value of $ \ \cos(x + y) \ = \ -1 + \varepsilon \ $ leads to two admissible values for $ \ x \ \  $ (and so two values *each* for $ \ y \ ) \ \ , \ $ indicating that there can be two sections of the curve along which points in the neighborhood give values close to the minimum possible for $ \ \sin ( \  - \pi·x \ - \ x^2 \ ) \ \ . \ $  We see this when we examine the values of this expression along the portions of the curve passing through $ \ A \ ( \ \approx \ -3.58 \ , \ \approx \ 0.439 \ ) \ \ , \ $ presented in the graph below.  (I don't know what a "good" parameterization for this curve would be.)

The easiest conclusion  to reach for this curve is that the self-intersections occur then at minima and maxima of $ \ \sin(xy) \ $ and $ \ \cos(x + y) \ \ , \ $ through which   two "trajectories" pass at each location in *different* directions.  When this happens, there will be more than one value for $ \ \frac{dy}{dx} \ \ , \ $ which the expression from implicit differentiation will not resolve.  We generally need a curve parameterization or some other sort of detailed analysis of the curve relation to determine what the (limiting) values of the multiple slopes are.

[image]